# A function satisfying a condition is a polynomial of degree $\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function s.t $f(x)=\frac12(f(x+r)+f(x-r))$ for every $r>0, x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq 1$.

This is a question given to me in a course about complex analysis. I was able to prove this problem without using tools of complex analysis (I looked at $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ and showed that $g(x)=g(1)x$), but I'm curious if there's a way to use complex analysis to simplify the solution. My idea was to look at a function $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $g(z)=\frac12(g(z+r)+g(z-r))$ for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $r>0$ and then showing that $|g(z)|\leq A+B|z|$ for some $A,\ B\in\mathbb{R}$ and then using Liouville's theorem, but I couldn't make any progress.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Liouville's theorem wouldn't apply for two reasons: it's only continuous, not differentiable/analytic, and it's a real function! Given the latter particularly, I don't think you're going to find much in the way of clever, exclusively complex analysis tricks, and I don't think any will be simpler than what you've done.